# Character classification in JavaCV

Tags: ocr, javacv

can anyone tell me the most accurate technique to classify the characters (A-Z and 0-9) in javacv. any example code will be very helpful.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cvFindContours() to find the characters of your image. (Your image should be pre-proccessed).

> Then use Neuroph (Java ANN Framework) to OCR. It is one the great ANN
>   Java Framework. [Neuroph Home Page](http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/) Neuroph has set of sample
>   codes, including OCR.

Try out Neuroph + JavaCV
Thankx